# Fiware Orion: booleans in subscription expression

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm using the expression system in Subscriptions, such as:

```
"q":"TC>20"
```

Is there a boolean value in this language? Can I write:

```
"q":true
```

For matching all events?
I also tried:

```
"q":1==1
```

Without success.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your use case you want a `q` expression to be true always. The following statement would achieve that purpose:

- `"q": "!_NOT_EXIST"` (assuming none of your entities has the `_NOT_EXIST` attribute)

However, why using a `q` statement at all? Ommiting `q` means "everything matches" which I think also achieves your use case.

Comment: Omitting 'q' really seems to be the way to go ... As a detail: any 'q' expression would just make the query more complex and thus lead to a slightly slower broker.